# What would be the best type of class to use for a module representation?

Tags: kotlin, android-multi-module

To clarify the title:
I've got a multi-module app that has 5 feature-modules, I've set up navigation etc. but currently for my bottom navigation bar everything is hard-coded, the paths to graphs + icons + titles, I'm trying to find a way to create a class / object of some sort that would let me to just do something like:

```kotlin
val nestedGraphsRoutes = listOf(
    ProductModuleInfo,
    CategoriesModuleInfo,
    SearchModuleInfo,
    ProfileModuleInfo,
    CartModuleInfo
)
BottomNavigation() {
    nestedGraphsRoutes.forEach { graph ->
        BottomNavigationItem(
            label = {Text(graph.title)},
            icon = {Icon(painterResource(graph.icon, null)},
            selected = {...},
            onClick = {navController.navigate(graph.routes.nestedGraphRoute)} // I want the "routes" to contain other strings as well
    }
}
```

however I currently cannot think what wound fit well here, I'm currently using simple objects and that's... not pleasant to work with

Thanks in advance,
cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding module representation is like holding data: why not a "[Data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html)"?

Data classes are a concise way of creating classes used mainly for holding data. They implicitly declare [component functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html), `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `toString()`, and others based on the properties declared in the primary constructor.

For example, in the context of your use case:

```kotlin
data class ModuleInfo(
    val title: String,
    val icon: Int,
    val routes: Routes
) {
    data class Routes(
        val nestedGraphRoute: String,
        // Add other strings as needed
    )
}
```

You can then create your instances like so:

```kotlin
val ProductModuleInfo = ModuleInfo(
    title = "Product",
    icon = R.drawable.ic_product,
    routes = ModuleInfo.Routes(
        nestedGraphRoute = "ProductNestedGraphRoute",
        // other strings...
    )
)

// Repeat for other modules
```

And then you can use these instances in your `BottomNavigation()` call:

```kotlin
val nestedGraphsRoutes = listOf(
    ProductModuleInfo,
    CategoriesModuleInfo,
    SearchModuleInfo,
    ProfileModuleInfo,
    CartModuleInfo
)

BottomNavigation() {
    nestedGraphsRoutes.forEach { graph ->
        BottomNavigationItem(
            label = { Text(graph.title) },
            icon = { Icon(painterResource(graph.icon), contentDescription = null) },
            selected = { /*...*/ },
            onClick = { navController.navigate(graph.routes.nestedGraphRoute) }
        )
    }
}
```

That way, the `ModuleInfo` instances are effectively replacing the hard-coded data in your `BottomNavigation()` call. Each module is represented by an instance of `ModuleInfo` and that instance carries all the necessary information (title, icon, routes) for the `BottomNavigationItem`.

That should give you a more flexible and clean way to organize your module information.